# Writing under the cursor in x86 assembly using video mapped memory

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, video-memory

I am writing a simple application that tries to use video mapped memory (Starting at address 0B800). For the most part I can write directly to that memory and the characters appear instantly on screen, but I find if I try to write directly under the cursor what ever I tried to write does not stick. Is there a way around this? How can I write directly under the cursor?

Currently using something like this to write to the memory:

```
mov word ptr ES:[DI], BX
```

where BX has the attributes and the character I want to write.

Comment: Non-zero odds that you are doing battle with your DOS emulator.  A true hardware cursor just isn't possible anymore on modern machines.  That's a battle that's hard to win, try another one.

Comment: Okay thank you for pointing that out, I just didn't have enough experience with this stuff to even realize that dosbox might be the problem!

Comment: Would moving the cursor to some off-screen position help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up what interrupts dosbox supports and int 33h was on the list. Calling int 33h with `ax = 2` hides the mouse, then after that the `mov word ptr ES:[DI], BX` worked just fine, finally I called int 33h again with `ax = 1` to make the mouse visible once again.